# php SQL Server mssql_select_db error

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Up until yesterday I have been happily connecting to SQL Server Express 2005 using PHP 5 on IIS 7.

Yesterday I started getting errors when selecting a database.

```
<?php
$link = mssql_connect('localhost,1433', 'login', 'password');

if(!$link) {
    die('could not connect to MSSQL');
}

 if(!mssql_select_db('database', $link)) {
    echo mssql_get_last_message();
    die('could not select db');    
}    
?>
```

This outputs the following:

"**Changed database context to 'database'.could not select db**"

So `mssql_get_last_message` is outputting `Changed database context to 'database'.` which seems all correct and isn't really an error message.  But then the mssql_select_db is still failing.

I have tested the following:

- The login is correct (you get a different error changing the username or password)
- The database exists (you get a different error if I use the name of a database that doesn't exist
- The login can connect to the database (you get a different error if you delete the database user in SQL Server)

I'm not sure what else to test.

Comment: What does `select state_desc, user_access_desc from master.sys.databases where name = 'YourDB'` return?

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the response - these are the results or your query:
state_desc = ONLINE, user_access_desc = MULTI_USER

Comment: any recent upgrades to anything? SQL Server Express 2005? PHP 5? IIS 7? any server restarts?

Comment: I'd been detaching, renaming and reattaching some databases just prior to the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Martin and Phil for their responses.  I created a new login and a new corresponding user which fixed the problem.