# SQL Server & Php impossible to use

Tags: php, sql-server

I wrote a class to connect a php page to Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Source code:

```
class DBManager{
    public static $server ="192.168.1.79";
    public static $database="db";
    public static $username ="user";
    public static $password ="pass";

    public function __constructor(){
}


    public function ricavaConcessionarioRicercato($codconc,$concessionario,$cap){
        include_once("Concessionario.php");
        $listaConcessionariTrovati = array();
        $connection = mssql_connect($server,$username,$password);
        mssql_select_db($database)or die('MSSQL error' . mssql_get_last_message());

        $querySQL = "SELECT DISTINCT [CodConc]
                                ,[Concessionario]
                                ,[Indirizzo]
                                ,[Mail]
                                FROM [Conserva_Pg].[dbo].[PLTWConcGestCAP]
                                WHERE CodConc LIKE '%$codconc%' AND Concessionario LIKE '%$concessionario%'". ($cap == "") ?"": "AND CAPdiGest LIKE '%$cap%'";
        $risultato = mssql_query( $querySQL);
        while($row = mssql_fetch_object($risultato)){
            $concessionario = new Concessionario();
            $concessionario->codConc = $row->CodConc;
            $concessionario->concessionario = $row->Concessionario;
            $concessionario->indirizzo = $row->Indirizzo;
            $concessionario->email = $row->Mail;
            $listaConcessionariTrovati[] = $concessionario;

        }
        mssql_free_result($risultato);
        mssql_close($connection);
        return $listaConcessionariTrovati;
    }

}
```

But when i execute the function i receive this warning:

> Warning: mssql_select_db() [function.mssql-select-db]: Unable to select database: in C:\Applicativi\P&G\GestioneConcessionari\DBManager.php on line 21
>   MSSQL errorChanged database context to 'master'.

After, i rewrite the function using ADODB connection:

```
class DBManager{

    public function __constructor(){


    }



    public function ricavaConcessionarioRicercato($codconc,$concessionario,$cap){
        include_once("Concessionario.php");
        $connSQL = new COM("ADODB.Connection"); 
        $connstr = "DRIVER={SQL Server};"; 
        $connstr .= "SERVER=192.168.1.79;DATABASE=db;uid=user;pwd=pass;"; 
        $connSQL->open($connstr); 
        $listaConcessionariTrovati = array();


        $queryconc = "SELECT DISTINCT [CodConc]
                                ,[Concessionario]
                                ,[Indirizzo]
                                ,[Mail]
                                FROM [Conserva_Pg].[dbo].[PLTWConcGestCAP]
                                WHERE CodConc LIKE '%$codconc%' AND Concessionario LIKE '%".$concessionario."%'";


        $rsta = $connSQL->execute($queryconc);
        if(!$rsta->eof()){
        $rsta->movefirst();
            while(!$rsta->EOF){
                $concessionario = new Concessionario();
                $concessionario->codConc = $rsta['CodConc']->value;
                $concessionario->concessionario =  $rsta['Concessionario']->value;
                $concessionario->indirizzo =  $rsta['Indirizzo']->value;
                $concessionario->email =  $rsta['Mail']->value;
                $listaConcessionariTrovati[] = $concessionario;
                $rsta->movenext();
            }
        }
        $rsta->Close();
        $connSQL->Close();
        $rsta = null;
        $connSQL = null;
        print_r($listaConcessionariTrovati);
        return $listaConcessionariTrovati;
    }
}
```

This script functions correctly! WHY????

Thanks so much..

Best Regards

Comment: Probably for the best that it doesn't work given it's a SQL injection attack waiting to happen.

Comment: SQL injection attack???

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: i know what is a SQL injection... but what concern with my problem?

Comment: To comment on the security: In your select-statement you have ...LIKE '%".$concessionario."%'"; This basically is the security hole of your current code. You should use PDO and prepared statements instead: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the connection when using `mssql_select_db()`

```
mssql_select_db($database, $connection);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer... i change the code line but the problem persists.

Comment: `$link_identifier` is not mandatory: «If no link identifier is specified, the last opened link is assumed.»

Comment: When you are inside of a class your variables shoud be like $connection = mssql_connect(self::$server,self::$username,self::$password);

Comment: nope... the problem persists... i try also to write this: $connection = mssql_connect("192.168.1.79","user","pass");

Comment: maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830237/php-sql-server-mssql-select-db-error